# Heat capacity of photons

Tags: thermodynamics, photons, radiation

I know that heat capacity is defined as the amount of energy required to increase the temperature of any given amount of substance by 1 Degree or 1 Kelvin . Since photons also have mass , is it possible that any given photon may have a specific amount of heat capacity ? If yes than how shall I calculate it ?

Comment: Photons are massless particles

Comment: Photons have no rest mass but they contain relativistic mass since they carry momentum and energy .

Comment: Photons are massless full stop. Anyhow the non-existence of the photon mass is not germane to this discussion. A photon gas can have a well defined heat capacity even though it is massless. See [this Wikipedis article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas).

Comment: It is crucial that you distinguish correctly between [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) and [specific heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Specific_heat_capacity) (which is equal to heat capacity per unit mass, as generally with the use of the word [specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific#Physical_natural_sciences.2C_including_physiology.2C_and_engineering)). If you don't mean to use the word in that sense, it shouldn't be near the words 'heat capacity' at all, particularly in this context.

Answer (score 6):

[Heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Extensive_properties) is a thermodynamic variable, i.e. when talking of particles it can be defined within [statistical thermodynamics](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/sp.pdf), **but not for individual particles.**

> Since photons also have mass,

A photon is an [elementary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon) with **zero mass**, spin and energy $h\nu$.

> Is it possible that any given photon may have a specific amount of heat capacity ?

No, it is impossible. In general individual particles cannot have thermodynamic properties which are statistical by construction. More so zero mass particles such as the photon.

Answer (score 2):

Heat capacity is defined as the amount the energy of a system changes as the temperature is changed while the system remains at constant volume, $$C_V\equiv\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_V.$$

Photons are massless bosons, which means their density of states is given by the Bose-Einstein distribution, $$n(p) = g[e^{E(p)/T}-1]^{-1}$$ in $\hbar=c=k_B=1$ natural units and where $g=2$ is the degeneracy of the particles, in this case 2 for the two polarizations possible for photons.  Therefore the energy of a gas of photons at temperature $T$ is, as $E=p$ for massless particles, $$E=\int d^3x d^3p\,E(p) n(p)=4\pi g V \int_0^\infty p^2 dp\frac{p}{e^{p/T}-1} = 4\pi g V \frac{\pi^4T^4}{15}.$$

Therefore the heat capacity for a gas of photons is $$C_V=\frac{8\pi^5VT^3}{15}.$$